# C# trim mac address regex matches from text file

Tags: c#, regex

How can I trim all valid mac addresses from multi vendor switch mac-address table dumps?

I've got the following so far...

```
        string strLineBuf = "Cisco 10 001c.aabb.ccdd Gi0/50";
        // string strLineBuf = "HP 001caa-bbccdd 50 10";
        // string strLineBuf = "Other 00:1c:aa:bb:cc:dd 50";

        // finds valid MAC addresses with space before and after
        Regex rex = new Regex(@"^.* ([0-9A-F]{2}[:.-]?){5}[0-9A-F]{2} .*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Match m = rex.Match(strLineBuf);

        if (m.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Valid MAC found in line :)");
            // trim MAC from line
            // save line to arraylist
        }
```

The input lines won't necessarily have the same number of chars before or after the MAC address.  With an input file such as:

```
Cisco 10 001c.aabb.ccdd Gi0/50
HP 001caa-bbccdd 50 10
Other 00:1c:aa:bb:cc:dd 50
```

I'd like an output of:

```
Cisco 10  Gi0/50
HP  50 10
Other  50
```

Comment: The only true MAC is :  "00:1c:aa:bb:cc:dd".  It appears the other strings may be some partial interpretation of the MAC.  The Mac contains the manufacturer, model, and serial number.  So some code determined that the other address where manufactured by Cisco and HP.  The last the code wasn't able to get manufacturer so it only gave back the raw MAC.

Comment: Thanks jdweng, yeah I just made up those mac addresses for testing purposes.  My actual input data will be a few hundred text files containing switch outputs of 'show mac address-table' and their equivalents for other switch vendors. Ultimately I'm looking to find which unique switch port a particular mac is connected to, my first step being eliminate all lines with >1 mac seen on the same port.

Comment: It is really difficult to help parse "text files" without good samples.  I've been parsing text files for 40 years and am very good, but can't help with limited data like you posted.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to tweak the Mac pattern but 12 minimum seemed reasonable hint to give to the parser to make it work.

```
var data = @"Cisco 10 001c.aabb.ccdd Gi0/50
HP 001caa-bbccdd 50 10
Other 00:1c:aa:bb:cc:dd 50";

var pattern =
@"^
   (?<Brand>.+?)
   (?:\s+)
   (?<MAC>[\w.:\-]{12,})
   (?:\s+)
   (?<Data>[^\r\n]+)";

Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select (mt => new
                    {
                       Brand = mt.Groups["Brand"].Value,
                       MAC   = mt.Groups["MAC"].Value,
                       Data  = mt.Groups["Data"].Value
                    }
             )
```

**Resultant Dynamic Entities**

[image]

Comment: Thanks OmegaMan!  This looks useful, I could drop these results into an arraylist then delete all rows wherever duplicates of  'Brand' and 'Data' exist.  Could you give me a working example of your code?  Cheers :)

Comment: @Ronnie, there is no need to *drop into an array list*  for the dynamic entities of the results shown above could be filtered directly.  As for working example...the above example answers the question. You just need to modify it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You're pattern already matched your sample data, so I just tweaked to actually match the entire mac address into a capture group so that a `String.Replace()` could be done to remove it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> data = new List<string>()
        {
            "Cisco 10 001c.aabb.ccdd Gi0/50",
            "HP 001caa-bbccdd 50 10",
            "Other 00:1c:aa:bb:cc:dd 50"
        };

        foreach (string strLineBuf in data)
        {
            // Finds valid MAC addresses with space before and after
            Regex rex = new Regex(@"^.* (([0-9A-F]{2}[:.-]?){5}[0-9A-F]{2}\s?).*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Match m = rex.Match(strLineBuf);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(strLineBuf.Replace(m.Groups[1].Value, String.Empty));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Cisco 10 Gi0/50
HP 50 10
Other 50
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gTC4Lp)